# Spring Boot @ManyToMany throws StackOverflowError

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I just want to establish a Many To Many relationship between "Student" and "Course". My classes and the output of the error are like the following:

```
public class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;
    String courseName;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses")
    List<Student> students;
}
```

```
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;
    String userName;
    String password;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "student_courses",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    @JsonIgnore
    List<Course> courses;
}
```

[StackOverflowError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbH4h.png)

How should I establish a Many to Many relationship without seeing that error?

Answer (score 1):

The `toString` method throws `StackOverflowError` probably because you attempted to also print the collection.

I suppose your `Student.toString()` looks like this:

```java
public String toString() {
  return "Name: " + userName +... + courses.toString();
}
```

And `Course.toString()`:

```java
public String toString() {
  return "Course name: " + coursename + students.toString();
}
```

When it attempts to stringify your Student, it will trigger `courses.toString()` which is `List.toString()`. Unless you are using an implementation out of Java Collection Framework, it should attempt to invoke `toString` method of each element.

Since both Collections are synchronized here, `course1.toString()` will invoke `student1.toString()`, which will invoke `course1.toString()` and cause an infinite recursive loop, leading to `StackOverflowError`.

To make sure this loop didn't happen, you can either:

1. Do not stringify the associated collection.
2. Provides a custom `toString()` that knows when to print the collection and when to not.

For example:

```java
// Student.java
public String toString() {
  // Don't concat courses.toString() here
  return "Name:" +... ;
}

public String toStringWithCollection() {
  // courses.toString() will invoke student.toString()
  return toString() + courses.toString();
}
```

Now if you invoke `student1.toStringWithCollection()` it should print exactly what you want (or maybe not).